# Check minimum value of a variable total cost and display alert message if less than minimum value

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I am trying to restrict the user to checkout on a shopping cart, if the total cost is less than £50.00 and instead show an javascript alert message.

I am amateur with javascript.

Any advise or help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Here is the example code:

```
<form action="Checkout.asp" method="post" name="Form1" onSubmit="return ValidData()">
<span id=total>{total}</span>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
function handlingcharge()
{
document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = '{CurrencySymbol}' + (dblTaxCost + (dblCostOfItems + dblFreight + dblHandling)).toFixed(2);
}

function ValidData()
{
if(document.Form1.total)
{
    if(document.Form1.total.value < 50)
    {
        alert('minimum order value is £50');
        document.Form1.total.focus();
        return false;
    }
}

if (!validateBudget()) return false;
if (!hasApproverEmail()) return false;
EnableFields();

if (!AgreedTerms()) return false;

return true;
}
```

Comment: are you getting any error with the above code?

Comment: It is always safer to do server side validations for total cost even after client side validation

Comment: You are missing some quotes for the span id

Comment: @hima i don't get any error but the validation is not working only for 'total' value and proceeds to checkout.

Answer (score 0):

```
funcation Validate()
{

   if(parseInt(document.getElementById('Total').innerHTML) <50)
   {
       alert('Your message');
       return false
   }

   return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but it did not work. 
I did not get any error message, but validation was not done.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. However I would suggest doing validation on the server side, due to the fact that client side would be vulnerable and easily by passed. Good Luck!

```
function validateTotal()
 {
   var totalValue = parseInt($("span[id=total]").text());
   if(totalValue < 50)
     {
        return true;
     }   
  }
```

Usage:

```
 if(validateTotal())
 {
    alert('Less than 50 dollars');
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but it did not work. 
I did not get any error message, but validation was not done.
And i do not have access to validate on server side :(

Comment: can you copy and show how the browser out put the total value part source code ?

Comment: <TR><td class="totalrow" id="firstcolumn" colspan="5" align="right"><b>{TotalItemCostCaption}</b></TD><td class="totalrow" id="lastcolumn" align="right"><b><span id=total>{total}

</span></b></b></TD></TR>

is this what you wanted?
{total} displays the total cost on the browser.

Comment: Does the browser output the total value exactly like this "£50.00" ?

Comment: modify the code and use this line to process the total value:                  var totalValue = parseInt($("span[id=total]").text().replace(/£/gi, ''));